# What was the significance of nun attire of the demon in The Conjuring 2?

Tags: analysis, the-conjuring-universe, the-conjuring-2

In the movie *The Conjuring 2* the demon *VALAK* is always shown wearing a **nun's** attire. Nuns are the ones who devote their life to god and well being of the society. So what is the significance? Why is the demon wearing the nun attire?

[image]

Comment: A sarcastic take on 'brides of Christ'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to an interview in [Week in Weird](http://weekinweird.com/2016/06/14/the-true-history-of-valak-everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-real-demon-from-the-conjuring-2/) it was (director) James Wan and the real-life Lorraine Warren's idea:

> While the name of the demon had been decided upon early on in the
>   process, Wan still hadn’t settled upon the actual design of the demon
>   until the 11th hour. While speaking to Lorraine in passing one day,
>   she mentioned that she had once encountered a swirling vortex with a
>   dark, hooded figure at the center. That bit of information was
>   translated into the demonic nun, which, believe it or not, was added
>   to the story in a series of re-shoots.

Also mentioned in [io9](http://io9.gizmodo.com/james-wan-explains-that-big-twist-in-the-conjuring-2-1781770378):

> "Because it is a demonic vision that haunts her, that only attacks her, [Director Wan] wanted something that would attack her faith. Something that would threaten the safety of her husband. **And so that was eventually how the idea of this very iconographic image of a holy icon cemented in my head.**"